# Can I setup a loopback audio device?

Tags: audio, devices, recording

If I can send audio to the output devices, then I can record the same audio as a wave. With filesystems, you can just setup a loopback filesystem and write binary data on a file instead of a device.

My question is: Can I send the audio signal to a (for instance) WAV file instead of my audio devices? How?

Comment: The video introduced four sound card loopback modes. https://youtu.be/pqV3P9zRyYc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Actually there are lots of ways. You can set up a sound dummy sound card device that you can just rip the data out of the device ... however this isn't a very useful format.

More useful to you is something like the `arecord` utility that allows you to eavesdrop on the alsa output stream and save it to several known formats. Basically anything that you can get to play over the alsa sound system can be copied to a standard format sound file.

[Similar tools exist for pulse audio](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/can-i-setup-a-loopback-audio-device/12558#12558).

Answer (score 8):

If your system, or just the application you want to record, is directing its output to a [sound server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_server), look into recording possibilities for that sound server. For example, on Ubuntu, the official sound server is [PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio), which comes with the [`parec`](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/FAQ#Whichprogramtouseforrecording) command (from the [`pulseaudio-utils` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pulseaudio-utils) [Install pulseaudio-utils http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pulseaudio-utils)). You may need to convert the output from `parec` into something usable with [SoX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX) (Ubuntu: [`sox`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sox) [Install sox http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sox)).

```
parec -r --rate=44100 | sox --type raw --rate 44100 - --type ogg recording.ogg
```

Comment: that didn't work for me, but this variation-on-the-theme did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio

Answer (score 4):

It is *supposed* to be possible to record directly in to Audacity, but I couldn't get that to work on my system (Ubuntu 10.10).
So following the instructions [here](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer#Linux) from the Audacity wiki, I use the `ALSA` playback device to divert the audio to a file.

This uses an `.asoundrc` file (in your home directory):

```
pcm.teeraw {
   type empty
   slave.pcm "tee:default,'/tmp/out.raw',raw"
   # 48000 S16_LE 2ch (aplay -t raw -f dat)
}
```

For recording from flash (on firefox), I use

```
FLASH_ALSA_DEVICE=teeraw firefox
```

The resulting file, `/tmp/out.raw` is in raw format so converting it needs knowing what the right parameters are.
Bizarrely, `lame` seems able to work this out for itself but `sox` needs to know it explicitly.
So the following all seem to work:

```
aplay -t raw -f dat -r 44100 /tmp/out.raw # to play
sox -r 44100 -b 16 -e signed -c 2 /tmp/out.raw /tmp/out.wav # to convert to wav
lame /tmp/out.raw # to convert to mp3
```

Comment: The link from the Audacity wiki is dead.

Answer (score 0):

There is a loopback driver in the ALSA tree, [aloop-kernel.c](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-driver.git;a=blob_plain;f=drivers/aloop-kernel.c;hb=e0570c46e3c4563f38e44a25cfac1f07ff5a02a8) (via [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Minivosc)); which you'd have to build yourself (and figure out its utilization as a a device through audio applications like `aplay`/`arecord`) ...