# Audio file as an audio input device

Tags: audio, voip

I want to play an audio file over VoIP in order that people can listen to it with a phone call. One way to do this would be to set up the audio file as an audio device where the audio starts playing at a specified time.

There are [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241356/play-mp3-file-using-pjsip) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845302/play-audio-file-over-voip) of playing my file over VoIP, but I'm still curious as to how you would set up the audio device that I discuss. What would I do?

You can see this as the reverse of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/can-i-setup-a-loopback-audio-device/12558).

Answer (score 2):

How about `cat`ing your audio file to your audio device, and use this audio device as input to the VoIP-program?

```
cat /path/to/my_audio.wav > /dev/audio
```

If `/dev/audio` is not the right device, you may find the right device (if using ALSA) with `aplay -L`.

Comment: If I could upvote this answer multiple times I would!