# Command line audio - piping for simultaneous playback and recording

Tags: linux, audio, pipe, alsa

I am trying to generate sound data, convert it and store it to a WAV format. I'm almost there - except I'd like to hear the generated sound **while** it is being "recorded".

This command just generates data and plays it back:

```
perl -e 'for ($c=0; $c<4*44100; $c++) {
             $k=1*sin((1500+$c/16e1)*$c*22e-6); print pack "f", $k;
         } ' |
aplay -t raw -c 1 -r 44100 -f FLOAT_LE
```

*(Note that if you press Ctrl-C here after sound stops playing, `aplay` may segfault)*

Using `sox` and `mplayer`, I can record fine - but I can hear no sound at the same time:

```
perl -e 'for ($c=0; $c<4*44100; $c++) {
             $k=1*sin((1500+$c/16e1)*$c*22e-6); print pack "f", $k;
         } ' |
sox -V -r 44100 -c 1 -b 32 -e floating-point -t raw - \
    -c 2 -b 16 -t wav - trim 0 3 gain -1 dither |
mplayer - -cache 8092 -endpos 3 -vo null -ao pcm:waveheader:file=test.wav
```

Note here that `play test.wav` (where `play` is from `sox` package, not `alsa`'s `aplay`) will state "Duration: 00:00:03.00" for the `test.wav` file. Also, this process seems to run faster than realtime, i.e. completes in (apparently) less than 3 secs.

By trying to cheat by using `tee` to capture the stream to disk,

```
perl -e 'for ($c=0; $c<4*44100; $c++) {
             $k=1*sin((1500+$c/16e1)*$c*22e-6); print pack "f", $k;
         } ' |
sox -V -r 44100 -c 1 -b 32 -e floating-point -t raw - \
    -c 2 -b 16 -t wav - trim 0 3 gain -1 dither |
tee test.wav |
aplay
```

Here apparently I get to hear the sound as it is generated - and `test.wav` is playable as well, however, `play test.wav` will report "Duration: unknown".

So I'd like to ask - is it possible to do something like the above "one-liner" command, to both generate, play and record a sound **at the same time** - however, *without* the need to install `jack`?

PS: some relevant links:

- [notes on linux audio file formats](http://linux.topology.org/audio.html)
- [Mplayer doesn’t stream from stdin without cache setting - Dag Olav Prestegarden](https://web.archive.org/web/20130708213633/http://dagolav.prestegarden.com/mplayer-not-eager-to-stream-from-stdin/)
- [command line - How to convert 16bit wav to raw audio - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383576/how-to-convert-16bit-wav-to-raw-audio/9384722#9384722)
- [Old Nabble - linux-audio-dev - audio recording through pipe using mplayer and sox sometimes has incorrect speed](https://web.archive.org/web/20131017052459/http://linux-audio.4202.n7.nabble.com/audio-recording-through-pipe-using-mplayer-and-sox-sometimes-has-incorrect-speed-td71680.html)
- [How to redirect the ALSA output to a file? | Software View](http://www.swview.org/node/213)
- [Can I setup a loopback audio device? - Unix and Linux - Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12541/can-i-setup-a-loopback-audio-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tee(1) to multiplex the stream, e.g.

```
perl -e 'for ($c=0; $c<4*44100; $c++) {
  $k=1*sin((1500+$c/16e1)*$c*22e-6); print pack "f", $k;
}' | tee >(sox -c1 -r44100 -t f32 - test.wav) \
         >(sox -c1 -r44100 -t f32 - -d) > /dev/null
```

You might also be interested in soxs' synth effect, which can produce most tones and sweeps, e.g.

```
sox -n -r 44100 test.wav synth 4 sine 100:1000
```